# How to convert string of length 32 to 256-bit Secret Key of AES in java? Is salt the only way?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, aes, secret-key

I want to convert a string of length 32 to 256-bit secret key of AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in java.
I found two answers:

1. By encoding and decoding -

   ```
   String password = "12345678910111211234567891011121"; // length-32
   byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password); // gives byte[] of size 24
   SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
   ```

   But byte[] of size 24 gives me for 192-bit key. I want 256-bit key for that exact string.
2. By using salt -

   ```
   public static SecretKey getKey(String password, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
       SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
       KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
       SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
       return key;
   }
   ```

   But I don't want to use salt as I need to generate it again.

Is there any other way to convert string of length 32 to 256-bit secret key? I will be using IV anyway. Can I use it as a salt? If not, what can I give for salt value and what is the standard way to generate salt?.

Comment: With an encoding that provides 32 bytes, e.g. `byte[] decodedKey = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you.....Will it be always same as length?

Comment: Unless this string is a base-64 encoded key it must be assumed to be a low-entropy quantity as in your example. In that case there are two steps to properly convert  it into a symmetric key. 1) Convert the string to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding, and then 2) Convert the byte array into a key using a proper salted PBKDF such as Argon2, or not-as-good-but-still-acceptable PBKDF2 as in your example. So it's not encode or salt, it's encode **and** salt.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk What can I use as a salt?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk will secure random be a better salt then?